# How to setup and use open SSL to client server application?

Tags: .net, security, openssl

Tool: Visual Studio 2012, Windows 7.
Application: Console Application (Both : Client & Server).

I have created one Client(HttpClient) Application and One Server(HttpListener) Application to Interact with Each Other on the same Machine. Now I want to secure transaction between this client server using Open SSL. How to do it?

Actually I am totally new for OpenSSL. It will be my first application with Open SSL.

How to setup and use Open SSL to this applications?
I have downloaded openssl-1.0.2h.tar.gz, openssl-1.0.2h-i386-win32.zip, asc, sha1 and sha256 files from [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/source/) and [Binaries](https://www.openssl.org/community/binaries.html).

Comment: HttpClient and HttpListener both support HTTPS with SSL|TLS out of the box, what specifically do you want the OpenSSL library/toolkit for?

Comment: Yes, you are right that HttpClient and HttpListner both support HTTPS but I want to Explore Open SSL  Architecture  and It's Workflow to Httpclient and HttpListner to provide security.